# how to restrict indentation while using jq filters on json file

Tags: json, jq, indentation

My input JSON file is:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "private": true,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "UI",
    "dependencies": {
        "xyz": "9.11",
        "abc": "5.0.0"
    }
}
```

When I use `jq .name=xyz`, the output will be printed as:

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "UI",
  "dependencies": {
    "xyz": "9.11",
    "abc": "5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Though my input file as proper indentation, after running the `jq` command the indentation is different.
How can I restrict the indentation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is currently no way to instruct jq to preserve the indentation style *per se*, but the `--indent N` and `--tab` command-line options give limited control over the style of indentation.  Thus, in the particular case given, one could achieve the desired effect using `--indent 4`.

Comment: For no indent (and no newlines) you can use `--indent 0` (version `1.6`). Helpful for filtering logs that are in JSON format.

Comment: For logs, use the -c command-line option.